# QGIS - Incorrect distance measurement using EPSG: 25832

Tags: distance, qgis, epsg

I have an issue regarding distance and area measurements in QGIS (includes buffer etc.). My CRS is set to EPSG: 25832 (Germany). Measurements differ substantially from those of my colleagues (using QGIS 3.28) and from Google earth/maps measurements (see below). My data I am using is also in EPSG: 25832. I am using QGIS 3.26.1.
A distance measurement of a fixed object in QGIS give the following results:

- Ellipsoidal (176.9 m)
- Carstesian (177.7 m)

Compared to the distance measurement of the exact same object in Google Earth:

- 105.3 m

I already compared my settings with those of my colleagues (they are all the same) and deleted QGIS (including registry) and reinstalled QGIS with no effect.